# how to disable button when the script runs first time in action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have action script bagging game i want that when the page is loaded add to current bag is disabled and it should get active when the add to new bag is clicked here is the code i am using for the baging game in action script

[image]

As image shown add to current bag first time should be inactive after pressing add to new bag then it should become active

```
    package {
import com.greensock.loading.LoaderMax;
import com.greensock.loading.XMLLoader;
import com.greensock.loading.ImageLoader;

import com.greensock.TimelineLite;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;

import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;

import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.GlowFilterPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.BlurFilterPlugin;

import appkit.responders.NResponder;

import bdesignet.utilities.keepRatio;

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.StageAlign;    
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

import flash.utils.Timer;

public class main extends MovieClip {
    private var _controlsTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite( { paused:true, onComplete:startGame } );
    private var _scoreTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite( { paused:true, onComplete:enableReplay, onReverseComplete:startGame } );

    private var _loadermainXML:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader("", { name:"mainXML", onComplete:onmainDataLoaded } );

    private var _files:LoaderMax;

    private var _glowCurrentBag:TweenMax;
    private var _glowNewBag:TweenMax;
    private var _glowReplay:TweenMax;

    private var _glowPicture:TweenMax;

    private var _xmlData:XML;

    private var _currentBagClicked:NResponder;
    private var _newBagClicked:NResponder;

    private var _replayOver:NResponder;
    private var _replayOut:NResponder;
    private var _replayClicked:NResponder;

    private var _currentItem:uint = 0;
    private var _currentBag:uint = 0;
    private var _currentBagItems:uint = 0;
    private var _currentBagType:String = "";
    private var _points:int = 0;

    private var _image:Bitmap = new Bitmap();

    private var _started:Boolean = false;

    private var _start:Date;
    private var _end:Date;

    private var _hours:Number = new Number;
    private var _minutes:Number = new Number;
    private var _seconds:Number = new Number;
    private var _totalTime:Number = new Number;

    private var _counterTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    private var _counterTimerEvent:NResponder;

    TweenPlugin.activate([GlowFilterPlugin, BlurFilterPlugin]);

    public function main():void {
        score.alpha = 0;

        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        _loadermainXML.url = "items.xml";

        _loadermainXML.load();
    }
    private function onmainDataLoaded(event:LoaderEvent):void {
        _xmlData = XML(_loadermainXML.content);

        _files = new LoaderMax( { name:"files", onComplete:onFilesLoaded, onProgress:onFilesProgress } );

        _glowCurrentBag = TweenMax.to(controls.addCurrentBag, 1, { glowFilter: { color:0xF7E9CF, alpha:.8, blurX:16, blurY:16 }, timeScale:2, paused:true } );
        _glowNewBag = TweenMax.to(controls.addNewBag, 1, { glowFilter: { color:0xF7E9CF, alpha:.8, blurX:16, blurY:16 }, timeScale:2, paused:true } );
        _glowReplay = TweenMax.to(score.replay, 1, { glowFilter: { color:0x695532, alpha:.8, blurX:16, blurY:16 }, timeScale:2, paused:true } );

        _glowPicture = TweenMax.to(_image, 1, { blurFilter: { blurX:20, blurY:20 }, alpha:0, timeScale:2, paused:true, onComplete:showItem, onReverseComplete:enableClicks } );

        for (var i:uint = 0; i < _xmlData.images.image.length(); i++ ) {
            _files.append( new ImageLoader(_xmlData.images.@folder + _xmlData.images.image[i].@url, { name:"image_" + i }) );
        }
        _files.load();


    }
    private function onFilesProgress(event:LoaderEvent):void {
        loader.value_txt.text = String(Math.round(event.target.progress * 100)) + " %";
    }
    private function onFilesLoaded(event:LoaderEvent):void {
        controls.numberBags.numberBags_txt.text = String(_currentBag);
        controls.remainingText.value_txt.text = String(_xmlData.images.image.length() - 1);

        _replayOver = NResponder.addNative(score.replay, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOverReplay);
        _replayOut = NResponder.addNative(score.replay, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOutReplay);
        _replayClicked = NResponder.addNative(score.replay, MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickedReplay);
        _replayClicked.paused = true;
        _replayOver.paused = true;
        _replayOut.paused = true;

        NResponder.addNative(controls.addCurrentBag, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOverCurrentBag);
        NResponder.addNative(controls.addCurrentBag, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOutCurrentBag);
        _currentBagClicked = NResponder.addNative(controls.addCurrentBag, MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickedCurrentBag);
        _currentBagClicked.paused = true;

        NResponder.addNative(controls.addNewBag, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOverNewBag);
        NResponder.addNative(controls.addNewBag, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOutNewBag);

        _newBagClicked = NResponder.addNative(controls.addNewBag, MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickedNewBag);
        _newBagClicked.paused = true;

        controls.addCurrentBag.buttonMode = true;
        controls.addNewBag.buttonMode = true;

        NResponder.addNative(score.emailLink, MouseEvent.CLICK, onLinkClick);
        score.emailLink.buttonMode = true;

        imageContainer.addChild(_image);

        _counterTimerEvent = NResponder.addNative(_counterTimer, TimerEvent.TIMER, onCounterTimer);
        _counterTimerEvent.paused = true;

        _controlsTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(loader, 1, { alpha:0, timeScale:2 } ));
        _controlsTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.addCurrentBag, 1, { alpha:1, x:237, timeScale:2 } ));
        _controlsTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.addNewBag, 1, { alpha:1, x:237, timeScale:2 } ), -0.5);
        _controlsTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.currentBag, 1, { alpha:1, y:280, timeScale:2 } ));
        _controlsTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.numberBags, 1, { alpha:1, y:280, timeScale:2 } ), -0.5);
        _controlsTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.remainingText, 1, { alpha:1, timeScale:2 } ));
        _controlsTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.timeText, 1, { alpha:1, timeScale:2 } ));

        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.timeText, 1, { alpha:0, timeScale:2 } ));
        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.remainingText, 1, { alpha:0, timeScale:2 } ));
        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.numberBags, 1, { alpha:0, y:416, timeScale:2 } ));
        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.currentBag, 1, { alpha:0, y:416, timeScale:2 } ), -0.5);
        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.addNewBag, 1, { alpha:0, x:467, timeScale:2 } ));
        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(controls.addCurrentBag, 1, { alpha:0, x:467, timeScale:2 } ), -0.5);
        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.from(score, 1, { blurFilter: { blurX:20, blurY:20 }, alpha:0, timeScale:2 } ));
        _scoreTimeline.append(TweenMax.to(score, 1, { alpha:1, timeScale:2 } ), -0.5);

        _controlsTimeline.play();
    }
    private function onLinkClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mailto:imran.husain@celeritas-solutions.com" + "?subject=Score&body=Score%20:%20" + _points + "\nDate%20:%20" + (_end.month + 1) + "/" + _end.date + "/" + _end.fullYear);
        //trace(request.url);
        navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
    }
    private function onCounterTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
        _end = new Date();
        controls.timeText.value_txt.text = returnTimeString(Math.round((_end.time - _start.time) / 1000));
    }
    private function startGame():void {

        _start = new Date();

        _counterTimerEvent.paused = false;
        _counterTimer.start();

        _currentItem = 0;
        _points = 0;
        _currentBag = 0;
        _currentBagItems = 0;

        _currentBagType = _xmlData.images.image[0].@bag_type;

        showItem();

        !_started ? (TweenMax.from(_image, 1, { blurFilter: { blurX:20, blurY:20 }, alpha:0, onComplete:enableClicks } ), _started = true):void;
    }
    private function onOverReplay(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _glowReplay.play()
    }
    private function onOutReplay(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _glowReplay.reverse();
    }
    private function onClickedReplay(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _replayClicked.paused = false;
        _replayOver.paused = false;
        _replayOut.paused = false;

        controls.numberBags.numberBags_txt.text = 0;
        controls.remainingText.value_txt.text = String(_xmlData.images.image.length() - 1);
        controls.currentBag.currentItems_txt.text = "";

        controls.timeText.value_txt.text = "00:00";

        _scoreTimeline.reverse();
    }
    private function onOverCurrentBag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _glowCurrentBag.play();
    }
    private function onOutCurrentBag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _glowCurrentBag.reverse();
    }
    private function onClickedCurrentBag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _xmlData.images.image[_currentItem].@bag_type != _currentBagType ? _points-=2 : _points+=2;

        _currentBagItems > 0 ? controls.currentBag.currentItems_txt.appendText(", ") : controls.currentBag.currentItems_txt.text = "";
        controls.currentBag.currentItems_txt.appendText(_xmlData.images.image[_currentItem].@name);
        _currentBagItems++;
        nextItem();
    }
    private function onOverNewBag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _glowNewBag.play();
    }
    private function onOutNewBag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _glowNewBag.reverse();
    }
    private function onClickedNewBag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _xmlData.images.image[_currentItem].@bag_type != _currentBagType ? _points++ : _points--;

        _currentBagType = _xmlData.images.image[_currentItem].@bag_type;
        _currentBagItems = 1;
        _currentBag++;
        controls.numberBags.numberBags_txt.text = String(_currentBag);
        controls.currentBag.currentItems_txt.text = _xmlData.images.image[_currentItem].@name;

        nextItem();
    }
    private function nextItem():void {
        _currentItem++;

        _currentBagClicked.paused = true;
        _newBagClicked.paused = true;

        _glowPicture.restart();
    }
    private function enableReplay():void {
        _replayClicked.paused = false;
        _replayOver.paused = false;
        _replayOut.paused = false;

        score.replay.buttonMode = true;

    }
    private function enableClicks():void {
        _currentBagClicked.paused = false;
        _newBagClicked.paused = false;
    }
    private function showItem():void {
        if (_currentItem < _xmlData.images.image.length()) {
            controls.remainingText.value_txt.text = String(_xmlData.images.image.length() - (_currentItem + 1));

            _image.bitmapData = LoaderMax.getLoader("image_" + _currentItem).rawContent.bitmapData;

            keepRatio.findValues(_image.height, _image.width, 268, 390, true);

            _image.x = keepRatio.newX;
            _image.y = keepRatio.newY;
            _image.height = keepRatio.newHeight;
            _image.width = keepRatio.newWidth;
            _glowPicture.currentProgress == 1 ? _glowPicture.reverse() : null;
        }else {
            //_end = new Date();

            _counterTimerEvent.paused = true;
            _counterTimer.stop();

            score.text.total_txt.text = String(_xmlData.images.@total_score);
            score.text.value_txt.text = String(_points);
            score.timeText.value_txt.text = returnTimeString(Math.round((_end.time - _start.time) / 1000));

            _scoreTimeline.play();
        }
    }
    public function returnTimeString($val:Number):String{
        _hours = Math.floor($val/3600);
        _minutes = Math.floor($val/60);
        _seconds = Math.floor($val-(_minutes*60));
        return (_hours > 0 ? String(_hours) + ':' : '' ) + (_minutes > 9 ?       String(_minutes) : '0' + String(_minutes)) + ':' + (_seconds > 9 ? String(_seconds) : '0' + String(_seconds));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the eventListener for add to current bag immediately.
Create a **boolean** (ie newBagPressed = false). 
When *Add to new bag* is pressed, test for the boolean. 
If it is false, set it to true and only then add the eventListener to *Add to current bag.*

Hope this helps :)

Comment: can you explain me more or edit some code please i am new to action script thanks